# Javascript: invoking objects like functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, invoke

Can I have a constructor that creates an instance, but when invoked executes a specific function?

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.bar= "some variable";

   this.invokeFunction = function(){
        return this.bar;
    }
    return .... // what to do here
};

var foo = new Foo();

return foo;       // return the instance of Foo:  { bar: "some variable" }
return foo.bar; // returns "some variable"
return foo() ;    // returns "some variable"
```

Comment: You don't need to return anything. `foo()` will throw an error since it's not a function.

Comment: Are you asking for a function that behaves differently when it's called with/without `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake it with something like this. Foo returns a function which has a `__proto__` pointing to its own prototype. The returned function is callable, an instance of `Foo` and has access to instance properties:

```js
var Foo = function(){
    function inner(){
        console.log("called")
        return "returned"
    }

    inner.__proto__ = Foo.prototype
    inner.bar= "some variable";
    return inner
};

Foo.prototype.someFn = function(){
    console.log("called prototype function")
    return this.bar
}

var foo = new Foo();

console.log(foo instanceof Foo) // it's an instance of Foo
console.log(foo.bar) // still has access to instance variables
console.log(foo())  // callable!
console.log(foo.someFn()) // prototype function with `this`
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class function, return a function that returns what you want. So something like this:

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.bar= "some variable";

   this.invokeFunction = function(){
        return this.bar;
    }
    return this.invokeFunction.bind(this);
};
```

Comment: If it works, I'd love if you accepted the answer :)

Comment: This doesn't really work: `var f = new Foo(); console.log(f.bar)` ---> undefined.